# Python Barchart from csv file

Tags: python, csv, plot

I have  a csv file as follow:

```
Statistic,Evap_a_lm,Evap_am,Evap_lm,Evap_od
STD_ctessel:,0.553843,0.572184,0.546684,0.568511
STD_htessel:,0.761471,0.938552,0.747172,0.919918
Mean_Bias_ctessel:,-0.290104,-0.248983,-0.310019,-0.267554
Mean_Bias_htessel:,-0.214769,-0.0868161,-0.233181,-0.103245
```

From this CSV file I would like to iterate through indexes and rows names components in order to produce barplots, like this one: [image]

For that I did produce the following code:

```
import os,sys,math,time
import csv
from matplotlib import rc
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import patches as mpatches
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
variables = ["Evap"]
names = ["od", "lm", "am", "a_lm"]
models = ["ctessel", "htessel"]
statistics = ['STD']
for variable in variables:
    for name in names:
        data = pd.read_csv("merged.txt", delimiter='\t')
        data.set_index('Statistic')
        for stat in statistics:
            for model in models:
                od = data.loc[[stat + "_" + model + ":"],[variable + "_od"]].astype(float)
                lm = data.loc[[stat + "_" + model + ":"],[variable + "_lm"]].astype(float)
                am = data.loc[[stat + "_" + model + ":"],[variable + "_am" + station]].astype(float)
                a_lm = data.loc[[stat + "_" + model + ":"],[variable + "_a_lm" + station]].astype(float)
                plt.title(variable + " " + stat, y=1.02)
                r1 = [1]
                r2 = [2]
                r3 = [3]
                r4 = [4]
                plt.bar(r1, od, width = barWidth, color="green", label='Original input')
                plt.bar(r2, lm, width = barWidth, color="yellow", label='Modis LAI')
                plt.bar(r3, am, width = barWidth, color="red", label='Modis Albedo')
                plt.bar(r4, a_lm, width = barWidth, color="blue", label='Modis LAI')
plt.savefig(outdir + station + "_" + "perf.pdf")
```

But unfortunately it is not working and I always have the error message that, obviously it cannot convert the string of the header to float:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Evap_od'
```

Does anyone knows a workaround?

Comment: your code sample generates  a different error when I try it: ```KeyError: "None of [['STD_ctessel:']] are in the [index]"```

Comment: @foundart Yes sorry I did a mistake in the name declaration, I just re-edited the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should fix most of your issues. Using pandas you can avoid all the extra code. You can then format it as you like from here.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('merged.txt')
df = df.set_index('Statistic')


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)

ax.grid(color='gray', linestyle='-', alpha=0.3)
```

[Example Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMkz4.png)